# Нужна ли запятая перед "во что"? И почему?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

По глупости своей не понимаешь(,) во что ввязываешься.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна. *Что* — это подчинительный союз (образует сложноподчинённое предложение), а здесь он в роли союзного слова.

Розенталь:
Запятой отделяются неполные или близкие к неполным придаточные предложения, например:
***Люди знают, что делают.*** || Одинаковая форма глаголов, наличие "что" и придаточное после главного, как и у вас.
*В старину **сова летала днем, где хотела**, и ничего не боялась.

Она жалела стариков, хотела, чем могла, помочь им.

Буду делать, что хочу.

Болтал, не знаю что.*